# Get an identity token for a client

Tags: identityserver4

Using IdentitServer4 I've create a client for a windows application.  To call into another authentication service (ie, AWS STS) I need to setup federation to my ID server and using an identity token.

Is it possible to get an identity token for a client?

The following code give me the access token but the identity token is null.

```
    var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync(Properties.Settings.Default.IdentityUrl);
    if (disco.IsError)
    {
      return false;
    }

    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, _executionContext.ClientID, _executionContext.Secret);
    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api.v1");

    _executionContext.AgentToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;  // OK
    _executionContext.IdentityToken = tokenResponse.IdentityToken; // NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, by definition a client cannot request an identity token for itself. Only on behalf of a user. From the [docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/terminology.html):

User

> A user is a human that is using a registered client to access
>   resources.

Client

> A client is a piece of software that requests tokens from
>   IdentityServer - either for authenticating a user (requesting an
>   identity token) or for accessing a resource (requesting an access
>   token).

The reason that a client can't request an identity token for itself is because it doesn't have (and can't have) a `sub` claim:

> The presence (or absence) of the sub claim lets the API distinguish
>   between calls on behalf of clients and calls on behalf of users.

Here's an [example](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html?#requesting-a-token-using-the-password-grant) on how to request an identity token on behalf of a user using the password grant.

Comment: I hate security stuff.  I wish we could just trust people  :)